# How to align rotated table texts?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, titles, rotating, multirow

I turned the captions of my table by 90 degrees.

Unfortunately, the headings do not fit to the table contents. Screenshot:

[image]

Can this be changed? I already tried `parbox` but that did not work.

Here is my table:

```
\begin{tabular}{cccc}       

    \noalign{\vskip\doublerulesep}

    & CSS & Canvas & SVG

    \tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]

    \multirow{1}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\mbox{Google Chrome}}} 
    & \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{images/screenshots/chrome_css3}
    & \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{images/screenshots/chrome_canvas}
    & \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{images/screenshots/chrome_svg}    

    \tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]

    \multirow{1}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\mbox{Opera}}} 
    & \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{images/screenshots/opera_css3}    
    & \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{images/screenshots/opera_canvas}
    & \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{images/screenshots/opera_svg} 

    \tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]

    \multirow{1}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\mbox{Mozilla Firefox}}} 
    & \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{images/screenshots/firefox_css3}  
    & \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{images/screenshots/firefox_canvas}
    & \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{images/screenshots/firefox_svg}   

    \tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]

    \multirow{1}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\mbox{Apple Safari}}} 
    & \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{images/screenshots/safari_css3}   
    & \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{images/screenshots/safari_canvas}
    & \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{images/screenshots/safari_svg}    

\end{tabular}
```

Relevant posts here on Stack Exchange could not help me.

Am I using `multirow` wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is similar to @HarishKumar 's approach.  But to get the titles to center on the rows, I set the height of the images.

Here though, I set the image `height`; the `graphicx` package will scale the width appropriately.  This allows you to label your rows and center them manually as I have done by bracketing the content between two `\hspace*{\fill}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \begin{tabular}{cccc}

    \noalign{\vskip\doublerulesep}

    & CSS & Canvas & SVG

    \tabularnewline[4ex]

    \rotatebox{90}{\parbox[t]{1.25in}{\hspace*{\fill}Google Chrome\hspace*{\fill}}}
    & \fbox{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-45}{\includegraphics[totalheight=1.25in]{example-image-10x16}}}
    & \fbox{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-45}{\includegraphics[totalheight=1.25in]{example-image-10x16}}}
    & \fbox{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-45}{\includegraphics[totalheight=1.25in]{example-image-10x16}}}

    \tabularnewline[4ex]

     \rotatebox{90}{\parbox[t]{1.25in}{\hspace*{\fill}Opera\hspace*{\fill}}}
    & \fbox{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-45}{\includegraphics[totalheight=1.25in]{example-image-10x16}}}
    & \fbox{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-45}{\includegraphics[totalheight=1.25in]{example-image-10x16}}}
    & \fbox{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-45}{\includegraphics[totalheight=1.25in]{example-image-10x16}}}

    \tabularnewline[4ex]

     \rotatebox{90}{\parbox[t]{1.25in}{\hspace*{\fill}Mozilla Firefox\hspace*{\fill}}}
    & \fbox{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-45}{\includegraphics[totalheight=1.25in]{example-image-10x16}}}
    & \fbox{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-45}{\includegraphics[totalheight=1.25in]{example-image-10x16}}}
    & \fbox{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-45}{\includegraphics[totalheight=1.25in]{example-image-10x16}}}

    \tabularnewline[4ex]

     \rotatebox{90}{\parbox[t]{1.25in}{\hspace*{\fill}Apple Safari\hspace*{\fill}}}
    & \fbox{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-45}{\includegraphics[totalheight=1.25in]{example-image-10x16}}}
    & \fbox{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-45}{\includegraphics[totalheight=1.25in]{example-image-10x16}}}
    & {\includegraphics[height=1.25in]{example-image-10x16}}

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't have the images you refer to.  So, I don't know whether they're already rotated or not.  What that means is that you may not need to use the `\rotatebox` on the `\includegraphics` calls.  If you don't need to make that call, then you can change `totalheight` to just straight `height`.  Though a word of caution, the images don't scale as you expect if you pass `demo` to the `graphicx` package:  hence my call to the image from the `mwe` package.

I believe that part of what's happening with your alignment is that you're center on the baseline of the image, which is the bottom of the image.

I've mucked around a bit with your `multirow` approach.  I'm not able to get a satisfactory looking result.  So I'd suggest just dispensing with that idea.

Comment: It has worked. The text is nicely centered. Thanks for that! A \ rotatebox was not necessary. My images are already rotated. But good to know that it is possible!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `multirow`, `parbox` will do it.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{cccc}

    \noalign{\vskip\doublerulesep}

    & CSS & Canvas & SVG

    \tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]

    \rotatebox{90}{\parbox[t]{1in}{Google Chrome}}
    & \includegraphics[width=1in]{images/screenshots/chrome_css3}
    & \includegraphics[width=1in]{images/screenshots/chrome_canvas}
    & \includegraphics[width=1in]{images/screenshots/chrome_svg}

    \tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]

     \rotatebox{90}{\parbox[t]{1in}{Opera}}
    & \includegraphics[width=1in]{images/screenshots/opera_css3}
    & \includegraphics[width=1in]{images/screenshots/opera_canvas}
    & \includegraphics[width=1in]{images/screenshots/opera_svg}

    \tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]

     \rotatebox{90}{\parbox[t]{1in}{Mozilla Firefox}}
    & \includegraphics[width=1in]{images/screenshots/firefox_css3}
    & \includegraphics[width=1in]{images/screenshots/firefox_canvas}
    & \includegraphics[width=1in]{images/screenshots/firefox_svg}

    \tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]

     \rotatebox{90}{\parbox[t]{1in}{Apple Safari}}
    & \includegraphics[width=1in]{images/screenshots/safari_css3}
    & \includegraphics[width=1in]{images/screenshots/safari_canvas}
    & \includegraphics[width=1in]{images/screenshots/safari_svg}

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]